# overloadable operators == and !=

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, operator-overloading

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Item {
   //MyFields
}

public class ItemCapsule {
    public Item MyItem { get; set; };
}
```

Somewhere in code, I write

```
ItemCapsule itemCapsule;
if (itemCapsule  != null && itemCapsule.MyItem != null) {
    //action
}
```

I might want to do this:

```
ItemCapsule itemCapsule;
if (itemCapsule  != null) {
    //action
}
```

So I created, in `ItemCapsule`, 2 methods to overload the operators

```
public static bool operator ==(ItemCapsule capsule, ???? what to write ????)
{
    return ???? what to write ????;
}

public static bool operator !=(ItemCapsule capsule, ???? what to write ????)
{
    return ???? what to write ????;
}
```

But, the problem is I do not know how to write the above two methods.

**I want to do the following**

```
ItemCapsule != null
```

**which actually is suppose to do the following**

```
ItemCapsule != null && ItemCapsule.MyItem != null
```

**How do I do it?**

Comment: why dont you just simply make a method called DoesEqual and NotEquals, and have two paramaters for what you are going compare.

Comment: Nobody will be able to read your code after you've done that. I think you should add a method or property to `ItemCapsule` called `IsEmpty`.

Comment: Overloaded operators should be used as sparingly as possible

Comment: Piling on... I also think the version with the explicit check is better: it's easier to understand and much less likely to contain subtle bugs.

Comment: Better to follow a pattern such as string.IsNullOrEmpty() rather than perverting the equality operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you do an overload for the `equals` too.

like so

```
        public static bool operator ==(ItemCapsule  x, ItemCapsule  y)
        {
            bool xnull, ynull;
            xnull = Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null);
            ynull = Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null);
            if (xnull && ynull) return true;
            if (xnull || ynull) return false;
            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(ItemCapsule  x, ItemCapsule  y)
        {
            bool xnull, ynull;
            xnull = Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null);
            ynull = Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null);
            if (xnull && ynull) return false;
            if (xnull || ynull) return true;
            return !x.Equals(y);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            return ((ItemCapsule )obj).Id == Id;
        }
```

Comment: Usually you should implement IEquatable<T> and implement both operator== and operator!= by calling Equals() and !Equals() respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Some extension methods would work better. Operators overloading should be the absolutely last resource, because it makes your code incomprehensible to anyone, including your future self.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this ItemCapsule item) {
        return (item != null && item.MyItem != null);
    } 

    public static bool Equals(this ItemCapsule firstItem, ItemCapsule secondItem) {
        return (firstItem.MyItem.Equals(secondItem.MyItem)); //see below
    }

    public static bool Equals(this Item firstItem, Item secondItem) {
        // perform the comparison of your 'Item' objects here
    }
}
```

I also like the suggested `IsEmpty` field in the class, for needing even less code.

Answer (score -2):

This would help you:

```
public static bool operator == (ItemCapsule capsule1, ItemCapsule capsule2)
{
    return capsule2 != null && (capsule1 != null && capsule1.MyItem == capsule2.MyItem);
}

public static bool operator !=(ItemCapsule capsule1, ItemCapsule capsule2)
{
    return capsule2 != null && (capsule1 != null && capsule1.MyItem != capsule2.MyItem);
}
```

Comment: It's not checking any thing

Comment: This is broken, `(null == null)` must be `true`

Comment: -1 Yes i think, you must be missing a point. You must check even references, cause it's might be not the same object allocated in heap. So you have to check it.

Comment: In this case, he just need to use if (itemCapsule  != null), So ItemCapssulate contains only one property MyItem. So we just need to check for unequality of the MyItem property. It is as good as saying capsule1.MyItem.GetHashCode() == capsule2.MyItem.GetHashCode().